# Google Play Games TurnBased Multiplayer starts without connections

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I trying to wrote turnbased multiplayer with Unity and google play games package. When users sucessfully login on google account and press "start button", i'm trying to create TurnBased match:

```
//Called with 1, 1, 0 params
public void StartMatch(uint minOpponents, uint maxOpponents, uint variant) {
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.TurnBased.CreateQuickMatch(minOpponents, maxOpponents, variant, this.OnMatchStarted);
}

void OnMatchStarted(bool success, TurnBasedMatch match) {
    if (success) {
        if (multiPlayerHandler == null)
            multiPlayerHandler = GameObject.Find ("MultiPlayerHandler").GetComponent<MultiPlayerHandler> ();
        multiPlayerHandler.StartGame ();
    }
}
```

But this OnMatchStartedMethod calling right after StartMatch method. Logcat write this:

```
Passing converted match to user callback:[TurnBasedMatch: mMatchId=ChoKCQjz2su-ywwQAhACGAAg____________ARDZ7pmjjczzwvcB, mData=, mCanRematch=False, mSelfParticipantId=p_1, mParticipants=[Participant: 'Ololo3994' (id p_1), status=Joined, player=[Player: 'Ololo3994' (id g05345227802167127790)], connected=True], mPendingParticipantId=p_1, mTurnStatus=MyTurn, mMatchStatus=Active, mVariant=429467295, mVersion=1]
```

Comment: Shouldn't you first config the  TurnBasedMatchConfig.Builder and then call createMatch() and pass in the TurnBasedConfigObject you created? ( I am not very familiar with the turn based multiplayer API)

Comment: I wrote this on Awake Function:
PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
I think that's' enoughf for it.

Comment: You should follow this small tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbYweTLvD-s it is really good.